# Activity indicator is not showing on updating current user Location ( locationManager )

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, location, activity-indicator

I am trying to show activity indicator while current location of user is updated and annotation is pined. Activity indicator works fine while updating pin using search bar by full address or postcode.

Also, i tried to add self. acitivityIndicator.startAnimation() on viewDidAppear() also in func:

```
    func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
    if self.showMyLocation {
        let locValue:CLLocationCoordinate2D = manager.location!.coordinate
        print("locations = \(locValue.latitude) \(locValue.longitude)")
        initialLat = locValue.latitude
        initialLong = locValue.longitude
        setInitialLocation()
        self.showMyLocation = false
    }

}
```

It takes time to find current location, but indicator is till not appearing. Do you have any idea why it is so?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to Stop Animation anywhere in your coding.
 **[activityIndicator stopAnimating];**

if yes then try to run your code without stopping your activity indicator

Comment: I have tried to put it only start, only end. But once the func starts updating annotations, screens is frozes, thats probably why i cant see animation.